# I can't figure out what is wrong with my semaphore implementation

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, semaphore, wait

I need to implement producers and consumers in C89 using semaphores.

I will admit this is for a school assignment, so I am going to use mostly pseudocode.

It took me forever to simplify my code, so hopefully someone can figure out what is wrong

There is one global variable:

```
threadQueue ready; //global queue that holds all the threads ready to be run
```

These are functions that I use in my code. I tried to make them self-explanatory:

```
NewThread(Function); //turns a function into a thread
RotateQueue(Queue); //rotates the Queue so the head becomes the tail and next becomes the head
Add2Queue(Thread, Queue); //adds a thread to a queue
RunThread(NewThread); //stops the current thread, and runs NewThread
RemoveHead(Queue); //removes the head of the queue and returns it
```

Here is how I designed the semaphore:

```
struct semaphore{
    threadQueue queue;
    int val;
}

wait(semaphore s)
{
    if(--s.val < 0)
    {
        Add2Queue(currentThread, s.queue);
        RunThread(ready.head);
    }
}

signal(semaphore s)
{
    if(s.val++ < 0)
    {
        Add2Queue(removeHead(s.queue), ready);
    }
    RotateQueue(ready);
    RunThread(ready.head);
}
```

Finally this is where I run my code:

```
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore taken = 0;
semaphore remaining = some number;

producer()
{
    while(1)
    {
        wait(remaining);
        wait(mutex);
        //critical section
        signal(mutex);
        signal(taken);
    }
}

consumer()
{
    while(1)
    {
        wait(taken);
        wait(mutex);
        //critical section
        signal(mutex);
        signal(remaining);
    }
}

main()
{
    thread produce = NewThread(producer);
    thread consume = NewThread(consumer);

    Add2Queue(produce, ready);
    Add2Queue(consume, ready);

    RunThread(ready.head);      
}
```

My code currently does this:

1. Starts produce thread
2. Switches to consume thread after signal(mutex)
3. Starts consume thread
4. Switches to a second consume thread? on wait(taken)
5. Starts second thread
6. Switches to a third consume thread?? on wait(taken)
7. SegFaults on Add2Queue

I am pretty sure signal() and wait() are incorrect and causing all my problems, but I can't figure out what I need to change.

Please help!

Comment: Your signal() and wait() are incorrect, as you suspect.  Neither of them are atomic.  The -- and ++ operators aren't even atomic, and you can have arbitrary interleavings of threads simultaneously inside your Queue routines.  Do you have a test-and-set() operation at your disposal?  Compare-and-swap()?  You need to think about all possible interleavings of instructions from different threads and write the code that prohibits the interleavings that are undesirable.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that your implementation isn't atomic, you have a serious logic bug in `wait()`. Your `wait()` unconditionally decrements the semaphore's value. What it should do is to check the value of the semaphore and ONLY if it greater than 0 should you decrement. Otherwise you loop.

Also be advised that this is one of those cases where the keyword `volatile` will come in handy, as your semaphore will presumably be used by multiple threads.